# weak warning in PyCharm: Unexpected argument

Tags: python-3.x, collections, pycharm, ordereddictionary

> This inspection reports discrepancies between declared parameters and actual arguments, as well as incorrect arguments (e.g. duplicate named arguments) and incorrect argument order. Decorators are analyzed, too.

^That's what PyCharm is telling me.  It's a weak warning, so my code runs fine.

```
import collections
var_dict = {}
var_dict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(var_dict.items()))
```

^This is the line of code in question.  I believe the warning has to do with the `OrderedDict` call.

I checked the [OrderedDict documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for Python 3.5, but I'm still nonplussed.

Why am I getting this warning?  I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.1

Comment: I posted [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17759) - having similar warns in Python 2. I believe it's a bug in their inspection (in pycharm 5) but let's see what they respond.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D What happened to your answer?  I was going to accept it in a day.

Comment: They deleted it - will repost it. That's ridiculous

Comment: The bug was assigned today - let's see :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I posted [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17759) - having similar warnings in Python 2. I believe it's a bug in their inspection (in PyCharm 5), but let's see how they respond.

**To moderators**: this is a valid answer [as recognized by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33738452/weak-warning-in-pycharm-unexpected-argument?noredirect=1#comment55521614_33738452). It is not a "comment". Please read carefully before deleting.

Comment: OP here.  Yes, a bug would explain why I have a weak warning still.  If no new news appears before tomorrow, when the bounty expires, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Your issue appears to have been fixed, but only in isolated cases. In particular [a new issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21415#u=1478850741679) identifies false warnings with e.g. `collections.defaultdict(None, dict(a=1))` or `collections.OrderedDict(dict(a=1))`

Answer (score 0):

So in my case I have a class with a `__new__` method which contains the allowed input arguments but I lacked the `__init__` method because my class is immutable. My code that has this warning looks like `instance = MyClass(a=1, b=2)`
Copying over the `__new__` method signature into `__init__` made this warning go away.